# Why does my <Style> dissappear?

Tags: css, documentation

Why does my style-tag disappear, in both my free site and my localhost site?
Where do I find the Wordpress guidelines that specify what can-not be done.

Example, where do I find: "Wordpress does not support the internal-style sheets and "style tag" in posts/pages, and it will be deleted from your post/page on the free hosted sites."?

Comment: Inline style tags/sheets aren't generally forbidden, if you're getting at that. Though it isn't recommended to use them extensively - or at all. Summarized, if you want concrete help, then you have to show and actually explain what you are doing.

Comment: I create a new post, paste the following into the text tab, then switch to visual, then back to text.  The HTML is gone just leaving "hello".
<style type="text/css" media="all"> 
 p { font: 1em Times serif; color: #c00; } h1 { font: 2em Times serif; color: #f00; } 
</style>
hello

Comment: Same thing with pages.  HTML dissappears when switching from text to visual to text.

Comment: You have to extend `$allowedposttags`, e.g. via `ìnit` hook. And via `tiny_mce_before_init` hook you have to make sure it is part of the inputed arrays `extended_valid_elements` element. Not going to show you how, because I think it is bad - very.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does remove `style` tags. While it allows HTML to some degree in post content, it's not really *meant* for full range of it. It's a *content*, not *markup* data.

You could use `tiny_mce_before_init` filter to adjust `extended_valid_elements` for TinyMCE instance.

See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297466/how-to-prevent-wordpress-3-9-tinymce-4-from-stripping-style-tags) for some examples.

Comment: Ok. I'm not going to use internal style sheets.
Should not the WP HTML stripper that is used in the Visual/Text Editor leave a comment behind after stripping out my well-thought-out CSS code,  something like:
<!-- Your CSS code as follows has been stripped out, because WP doenst like it. Your unliked code follows in this comment....Have the nicest of days.-->

Comment: Thank you Rarst,
As a newbie, I have learned that its not Wordpress per se that is at issue.
It is the [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE)  wysiwyg online editor that Wordpress uses.